# Finding only strings starting with a number using MySQL LIKE

Tags: mysql

How can I find strings in a table where the first character is a number?

I'm using MySQL LIKE as follows

```
SELECT   DISTINCT label_no_country
FROM     releases
WHERE    label_no_country LIKE '$letter%'  
ORDER BY label_no_country
```

where `$letter` is a letter between A-Z (depending on the input)

So if `$letter == 'A'` then it will show all entries where the first letter is A.

How can I run this query so that it will show records that start with numbers?

e.g.

```
1st record
```

cheers!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You might want to use Regular Expressions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT label_no_country FROM releases 
WHERE label_no_country 
REGEXP '^[0-9]'
```

See [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE label_no_country >= '0' AND label_no_country <= '9zzzzzzzzzzzzz' -- Insert as many z:s as the field can hold
```

**EDIT:**
Or better yet,
Just put in the character that is just after 9 in your collating sequence:

```
WHERE label_no_country >= '0' AND label_no_country < ':' -- assuming : is the character after 9 in your collating sequence
```